# Mongodb random aggragate query with find condition

Tags: php, linux, database, mongodb, aggregation

I am using mongodb with php and I have a database from which I am able to get one random record everytime through aggregate query but I specifically need only that random record in which language is set to english. I have a "lang" field set in each record already.

Currently I have the following piece of code to fetch random record.

```
$dbname = 'project';
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"); 
$videosdb = $m->$dbname->videos;
$randvideo = $videosdb->aggregate(array('$sample'=>array("size"=>1)));
```

Can anyone help!

Comment: You can use `$match` to filter the data... `$videosdb->aggregate(
array('$match'=>array('languate'=>'english')),
array('$sample'=>array("size"=>1))
)`

Comment: Thankyou it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find thew documents with `"lang" = "english"`, you can use `$match` condition in aggregate like this:

```
db.articles.aggregate(
    [ { $match : { author : "dave" } } ]
);
```

More details can be find here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

In your case query will look like  :

```
$videosdb->aggregate(
          array('$match'=>array("language"=>"English")),
          array('$sample'=>array("size"=>1)));
```

Comment: Great, please accept/upvote the answer if it helps you :)